# Are the angreal / sa'angreal / ter'angreal specific to saidar or saidin?

Tags: the-wheel-of-time

In *The Shadow Rising*, Moiraine warns Rand that a male Forsaken may try to use the Callandor (a sa'angreal) to which he replies that he has set a trap for anyone who tries to pull it out of the stone.

I am still in the fourth book and I am not sure if it is explained in later books. It seems that Callandor can only be used to amplify saidin. Do other angreal/sa'angreal/ter'angreal exhibit this kind of selectivity towards either saidar or saidin.

Are there any *angreal that are non-selective?

From the glossary:

> Rumors of angreal usable by both male and female have never been confirmed.

This statement does cast some doubt on the selectivity of *angreals.

Comment: your second question is deep spoilers to later books. so you may just want to RAFO (read and find out)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

All *Angreal* and *Sa'angreal* are specific to *saidar* or *saidin*. They are completely unusable by the opposite power. This is backed up by *The Wheel of Time Companion*'s entry on *sa'angreal*:

> As with *angreal*, there were male and female *sa'angreal*.

*Ter'angreal* are a toss up:

1. some can be either male or female attuned.
2. some require both male and female to function
3. and some draw their own *saidar* and/or *saidin* to work and can be used even by non-channelers.

At your point in the story most of the specific *ter'angreal* are probably spoilers, but I believe you have encountered the doorway *ter'angreal* in the basement of the Stone in Tear, which is an example of a *ter'angreal* used by men and women.

This becomes far more apparent in the later books, but *Callandor* is the prime example for a male *sa'angreal*.

Comment: Also am I right in assuming that the White Tower has confiscated most male \*angreal they could find or are they as common as female \*angreal. (*sorry for multiple questions*)

Comment: @WYSIWYG the white tower cant tell what male Angreal's are, since they would simply be a figurine or other object in their hands, so unless they knew a male was using them, they would not know the difference between a male angreal and trash, this leads to there being a very low number of male angreal/sa'angreals in the books, because people simply tossed them out.

Comment: @WYSIWYG female *angreal* are vastly more common in the story that male ones; its never explained outright but I think the implication is that any male angreal that were discovered during the breaking (either because they were recognized, or were taken from male Aes Sedai that were using them, or ) were promptly destroyed. Afterward, no one knew how to make anymore.

Comment: Thanks @MikeEdenfield but Himarm's theory also seems plausible that probably nobody but men who can channel can really distinguish an \*angreal from just a random object.

Comment: that's probably true *now*; in the Age of Legends when men and women were channeling together all the time I suspect (and there's very strong evidence late in the series) that they would have recognized many of each other's *angreal*.

Comment: The ter'angreal actually use saidar and/or saidin to operate, even if the person activating it is not a channeler. They can draw the Power on their own.

Comment: @MikeEdenfield My hypothesis would be that many of those *angreal* were used by the 100 Companions, and were subsequently destroyed or lost during the backlash and the following madness.

Comment: @CreationEdge that would be your hypothesis :P

Comment: Thanks @Himarm. It would be great if there was a conclusive statement somewhere, rather than conjectures to say that \*-angreal are selective. That would not be a spoiler I guess (It is just a fact of the universe).

Comment: @WYSIWYG There's never any indication or hint that it's to the contrary, not only in the entire series but in any of the interviews with Team Jordan. *Sa'angreal* and *angreal* are either for *saidin* or *saidar*, but not both.

Comment: @WYSIWYG they do say conclusivly in the books, i just didnt feel like combing through the 14 books to find a quote >.< lol, but im pretty sure moraine states it in regards to her angreal and in relations to callandor. but to make an angreal or sa angreal you have to Grow it by feeding it either saidar or sadin which is why its locked to a specific type

Comment: Can you have a look at my edit (@MikeEdenfield you too). Why does the glossary say that "Rumors of angreal usable by both male and female have never been confirmed"?

Comment: @WYSIWYG there is never a confirmation of this in the books, until the encyclopedia comes out next month thats as good as it gets. but it also possibly could be in reference to the intended purposes of callindor, however, that is major spoilers so ill leave it at that.

Answer (score 8):

First of all, it's important to note that, despite the similarities in name, *angreal* and *sa'angreal* are very different from *ter'angreal*.

The first two are only used to enhance the amount of the One Power someone can channel; the distinction between the two is pretty blurry, but essentially boils down to "*sa'angreal* are just souped-up *angreal*". And yes, as you surmise, every one we ever see, or even hear of, in the story is keyed to either *saidin* or *saidar*. It's *possible* but highly unlikely that any of them can be used by both.

One example of why we believe this is true, which we learn a bit about in *The Shadow Rising*, are the statues Rand find in Rhuidean. These statues are actually *ter'angreal*, but they are tied to a pair of *sa'angreal* - one for men and one for woman. Specifically, they're access keys to gigantic statues, called the Choedan Kal. (This female one is the statue that starts "glowing" on the Sea Folk's island in *The Great Hunt*.)

Note that during his fight with Asmodean, *both* statues are present in Rhuidean, but Rand and Asmo fight over possession of the male. The fact that that two statues were built, one specifically male and one specifically female, combined with the fact that neither Rand nor Asmodean attempted to use the second, seems to imply that this male/female distinction is hard-coded into the process of making an *angreal*.

---

*ter'angreal*, on the other hand, are a totally different question. These are basically "magic items", imbued with some built-in portion of the One Power at creation. Who can use them is entirely up to the person who created it -- in some cases, they are tied to one gender or the other, in some cases either gender can use them. In some cases, you need to channel to use a *ter'angreal* while others can be used by anyone who knows the process.

As an example, one *ter'angreal* we see and hear a lot about from very early on is the Aes Sedai Oath Rod. It's probably obvious from the beginning that this is a *ter'angreal* and that you need to channel to activate it. We eventually learn that this *ter'angreal* is *not* gender-specific, the Aes Sedai just have no idea what its original purpose is.

> It's actually a "binder", and was used to punish Age of Legends channelers who broke the law.

Answer (score 0):

I found some references which say that angreal and sa'angreal are specific to either saidin or saidar. As Mike Edenfield mentioned, this reference is made at the end of the fight between Rand and Asmodean in *The Shadow Rising*. However, this still cannot be counted as an explicit statement.

---

*Lanfear referring to the ter'angreal that links to the sa'angreal of Cairhien (man with a globe).*

> Keep it, certainly. To me it is nothing but a figurine.

Similarly, the twin of this ter'angreal, that links to a sa'angreal (woman with the globe) is useless to men.

> Kicking aside pieces of what seemed to be spiraled glass tubes, he shoved a plain-carved chair of red crystals aside and picked up a foot-tall figurine, a robed woman with a serene face, worked in white stone, holding up a clear sphere in one hand. Unbroken. As useless to him, or to any man, as its male twin was to Lanfear.

Comment: That's not quite saying what you think it is, except maybe by implication. Your quotes say that the ***ter'angreal*** access keys are specific to *saidin/saidar*, which probably (not positively) means those particular *sa'angreal* are. Doesn't say anything about *angreal* and *sa'angreal* in general.

Comment: @randal'thor. True. I did not think about it. Do you know of any explicit reference?

Comment: If I did, I'd have posted an answer myself :-)

Comment: @randal'thor I am still keeping this answer. Perhaps I'll add more points to it as I read more.